# pgfplotstable: Problems with data from \pgfplotstableread

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I would like to store data for a `pgfplot` inside my source file, without creating an extra file. However, there seems to be a difference between loading the data from an external file (provided here via `filecontents`) and storing it in a macro using `pgfplotstableread`.

The code below runs when `data.dat` is loaded by the `addplot`s, and causes errors when the second file name (see comment in the source code) is replaced by the table macro `\data`.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14, small}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
x   error   y   label
-0.3294 0.0012  -1  \num{-0.329(2)}
-0.3296 0.0012  -2  -0.330(2)
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableread{
x   error   y   label
-0.3294 0.0012  -1  \num{-0.329(2)}
-0.3296 0.0012  -2  -0.330(2)
}{\data}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmax=-0.293,
    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{label} \as \labela},
    nodes near coords align={horizontal}]
\addplot+[only marks, error bars/.cd, x dir=both, x explicit] 
    table[x=x,y=y,x error=error] {\data};
\addplot [nodes near coords={\labela}, only marks, mark=none] 
    table[x expr=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}, y=y] {data.dat};  % replacing data.dat with \data results in errors
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to achieve the same result in both cases? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You encountered the already known bug again which is already reported at https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/109/.

Comment: So it has to do with `visualization depends on` rather than the content of that specific column.

Comment: That is what the bug report states, yes.

Answer (score 1):

After the bug had been filed by @Stefan Pinnow, I found that problems with `\pgfplotstableread` also occur for matrix plots. So there is not only an issue with `visualization depends on`.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.14, small, scale only axis}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
x   y   Val
1   1   1
2   1   0
1   2   0
2   2   1
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableread{
x   y   Val
1   1   1
2   1   0
1   2   0
2   2   1
}{\data}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[width=2cm, height=2cm, enlargelimits=false, title=filecontents]
    \addplot[matrix plot, mesh/cols=2, point meta=explicit]
        table[meta=Val] {data.dat};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[xshift=4cm, width=2cm, height=2cm, enlargelimits=false, title=pgfplotstableread]
    \addplot[matrix plot, mesh/cols=2, point meta=explicit]
        table[meta=Val] {\data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the record: This is another bug which is reported at https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/192/.